# Getting LINK error : Extern in C++. How to access the value of a variable which is modified in File A.CPP in another file File B.CPP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, extern

IN my C++ code I want to make use of a variable "VarX" in a file "B" which is actually modified in another  file "A". 
So I had a look @ the following link & used extern concept.

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

> error LNK2005: "unsigned int VarX" (?VarX@@3IA) already defined in
>   ***.obj.

My scenario is as follows:

```
File1.h
extern unsigned int VarX;

File2.cpp
#include File1.h
unsigned int VarX = 101;

File3.cpp
#include File1.h
unsigned int temp = VarX;
```

**IMP NOTE: In the header file File1.h there are many other structure definitions and also many othe rdefinitions apart from the Extern definition.**

Can someone help me in this. How shall I read the Value of VarX which is modified in File2.cpp in another File File3.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't accessibility, but a multiple definition. The error message is pretty clear, somewhere in the code you're redefining `VarX`.

Common causes can be:

- invalid build - have you cleaned the build before compiling?
- you have multiple `unsigned int VarX = 101;` or a `unsigned int VarX;` somewhere (in a header or an implementation file), without an `extern` declaration.
- you `#include "File2.cpp"` somewhere in the code, causing it to be compiled multiple times.

My bet is on the second possiblity.

Comment: Yes I removed the multiple declarations. I had declared multiple times after having look @ one of the stackoverflow link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c" .  Now I removed the multiple declations. But Still I am getting the same LINK error. :(

Comment: Yes I did clean the entire solution & rebuilt entire soln. But stil getting same link error.

Comment: ANy inputes or pointers in this direction of fixing this prob would be very much appreciated :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: This ***.obj is the name of the CPP source files which #include this header file File1.h where I have declared my extern varaible.

Comment: In *** .obj "***" is the placeholder for all those CPP source files which #include the header file File1.h which has the extern definition.

Comment: @codeLover ok so you get this error for **ALL** files that include File1.h? That means there's something wrong in the header. Post the full code in the header.

Comment: No there is no error in the header file File1.h because, if I remove this extern declaration from the hedaer file than the solution builds perfectly fine. The Link error gets introduced only if I place the extern declaration line "extern unsigned int VarX;

Comment: @codeLover I beg to differ. Can't help you if you don't post the code. As it is no, there's no error.

Comment: I studied my code in detail. Your answers helped me and I got rid of the previous error. But now getting a different error. Again a Link error:: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol unsigned int VarX" (?VarX@@3IA) in file File2.cpp

Comment: @codeLover as that's a different issue, please post a different question.

Comment: Pardon me I am not supposed to post d code as a protocol followed @ my workplace. It would be helpful if u can kindly help me figure out the cause and help in fixing this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No its not a different issue; although the error is different, the issue is not deviating in any way from the title or purpose of my question posted in stackoverflow.

Comment: SInce its not a different issue it would be very helpful if you can help me figure out the fix.

Comment: @codeLover The code is different now, that's why I'm saying you should post a new question. I'd be glad to help (if I can).

Comment: Ok sure I will post a different question right now & expect a speedy help as always in stackoverflow. Thanks.