# Extern in C++: For the extern VarX variable:: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int VarX" (?VarX@@3IA)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors, extern

As a continuation of my previous question in stackoverflow:
[Getting LINK error : Extern in C++. How to access the value of a variable which is modified in File A.CPP in another file File B.CPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298041/getting-link-error-extern-in-c-how-to-access-the-value-of-a-variable-which)
IN my C++ code I want to make use of a variable "VarX" in a file "B" which is actually modified in another  file "A". 
So I had a look @ the following link & used extern concept.

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int
>   VarX" (?VarX@@3IA)

My scenario is as follows:

```
File1.h
extern unsigned int VarX;

File2.cpp
#include File1.h
VarX = 101;

File3.cpp
#include File1.h
unsigned int temp = VarX;
```

**IMP NOTE: In the header file File1.h there are many other structure definitions and also many othe rdefinitions apart from the Extern definition.**

Can someone help me in this. How shall I read the Value of VarX which is modified in File2.cpp in another File File3.cpp.

Comment: `VarX = 101;` is  not valid as declaration or initialization in C++. Is that your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `VarX` in global scope, which I'm assuming you're not doing now, since otherwise it wouldn't even compile:

```
//File2.cpp
#include "File1.h"
unsigned int VarX = 101;  //this has to be outside any code block or namespace
                          //or class...
```

Comment: Excellent. It worked. :) Thanks a lot. Stackoverflow rocks. BUt I had a query. Why is it that I need to declare VarX only in File2.cpp & how come I am not getting any such errors in File3.cpp where I am making use of this varibale "VarX" which was assigned earlier in File2.cpp. ? Can you please clear my doubt? Thanks :)

Comment: @codeLover because that's what one definition rule means. You only define a variable **once**, in your case, `File2.cpp`. The `extern` declaration only means *"this variable is defined somewhere, you can use it."*

Comment: Ok thank you. And I think you told me to define the variable outside of all functions, classes etc, (in global scope of File2.cpp) because, its been declared as extern in the header file & we want to make use of this definition in other files too.  Thanks a lot for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have File1.cpp
with following content:

```
unsigned int VarX = 0;
```